# ZipEntry.isDirectory() and Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> only see directory contents, not the directory

Tags: java, zip

I'm working on looking through a .zip file to confirm that all the contained files are named correctly, and running into some trouble. Here's the file hierarchy:

```
-.zip
  -dir
    -file1
    -file2
    -file3
  -file4
  -file5
  -file6
```

Code:

```
for (Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e = zf.entries(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
            ZipEntry entry = e.nextElement();
            System.out.println("ZipEntry name: " + entry.getName());
            ...
}
```

Usual output:

```
ZipEntry name: dir/file1
ZipEntry name: dir/file2
ZipEntry name: dir/file3
ZipEntry name: file4
ZipEntry name: file5
ZipEntry name: file6
```

The desired output would also contain

```
ZipEntry name: dir/
```

Strangely enough, I have one test case where I get the desired output: when using a .zip of identical hierarchy that was emailed to me. Whenever I use the .zips that I have compressed on my machine, I get the "Usual output." I'd really like to have consistent behavior, but I can't figure out what's going wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There aren't really directories in a zip file. There are entries. And [`ZipEntry#isDirectory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#isDirectory%28%29) checks if the name of the entry ends with a `/` to determine if it should be considered a directory. So what your zip file contains is

```
dir/file1
dir/file2
dir/file3
file4
file5
file6
```

For that strange case, the zip probably actually contains

```
dir/   // the entry won't actually have any content though
dir/file1
dir/file2
dir/file3
file4
file5
file6
```

This is useful for zip file managers to determine how entries should be extracted.